# Creating an object from the string value of input field

Tags: javascript

I have an input hidden field similar to :-

```
< input type="hidden" name="dateRange" id="dateRange" value="'2013-04-03','2013-04-04','2013-04-05','2013-04-10'"/>
```

I need to create an object in javascript using this input field's value. like:-

```
var dates_allowed = {
      '2013-04-03': 1,
      '2013-04-04': 1,
      '2013-04-05': 1,
      '2013-04-10': 1,
};
```

I tried with the following;

```
var dateRange=document.getElementById("dateRange").value;
var dates_allowed_Array = dateRange.split(",");
var dates_allowed1 = {};
for (i=0; i<dates_allowed_Array.length;i++) {
    var innerloop = dates_allowed_Array[i] ;
    dates_allowed[innerloop]=1;
    }
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Please explain _"it did not work."_ Did you see any errors in the console?

Comment: `var dates_allowed1 = {};` typo here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have a typo. You declared `dates_allowed1` but then used `dates_allowed`

When I fixed that it worked fine, as you can see by this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Gfj2/

Fixed code:

```
var dateRange=document.getElementById("dateRange").value;
var dates_allowed_Array = dateRange.split(",");
var dates_allowed = {};
for (i=0; i<dates_allowed_Array.length;i++) {
    var innerloop = dates_allowed_Array[i] ;
    dates_allowed[innerloop]=1;
}
```

Comment: I had just made a fiddle for this same demonstration but you beat me to the answer. Upvoted. @user2241885 It's not clear to me why you want to change the array to an object - just use the array because you have the same values.

Answer (score 0):

var dates_allowed1 should be var dates_allowed

Also, do you want to strip the single quotes or leave them on?